# Rebuild columns excel

Tags: excel, pivot, lookup

Im a excel beginner and cant find any solution for this fast on the web. Don't know exactly what to search for.

Here is how my excel look like:

[image]

And here is what im trying to achieve:

[image]

Can someone explain in a simple way how i can do this?  Thanks!

***> !!Tried the solution on my real data and now i have a new problem :(

> !!
>
> I dont have all values for every person in the Type Column. It looks
>   like this.***

[image]

Answer (score 1):

***Edited*** to account for re-worded problem

If you have O365 with Dynamic arrays and the `UNIQUE` and `FILTER` functions, you can do the following:

- Create a Table from your data

Then, for formulas for your results table:

```
G1: ID
G2:  =UNIQUE(Table1[ID])

H1: Name
H2: =@FILTER(Table1[Name], Table1[[ID]:[ID]]=$G2)

I1:    =TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(Table1[Type]))
I2 :   =@IFERROR(FILTER(Table1[[Value]:[Value]], (Table1[[ID]:[ID]]=$G2)*(Table1[[Type]:[Type]]=I$1)),"")
```

- Select `I2` and fill right to `xxx2`  (where xxx is at least as far to the right as you have, or might have columns
- Select `H2:xxx2` and fill down at least as many rows as you have unique ID's

-------[image]---

Another option, if you have Excel 2010+, would be to use `Power Query` (aka `Get & Transform`).

- `Get & Transform` from Table/Range
- Select the `Type` column
- Values Column -- `Value`
- Advanced Options -- `Don't Aggregate

[image]

- Close and Load

[image]

Comment: Your my hero! Thanks!

Comment: I edited my question because i found a new problem when i wanted to do this with my real data. Any idea how to solve next problem ?

Comment: @user2210516 See my edit for how to handle the problem with formulas. Power Query method will work without changes.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using several formulas.

To find the distinct Id

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$10,AGGREGATE(15,6,(1/(COUNTIF($A$14:A14,$A$2:$A$10)=0))*ROW($A$2:$A$10)-1,1))
```

Copy formula down.

To find names

```
=VLOOKUP(A15,$A$2:$B$10,2,0)
```

Copy formula down

To find type values

```
=INDEX($A$2:$D$10,AGGREGATE(15,6,(1/(($B15=$B$2:$B$10)*(C$14=$C$2:$C$10)))*ROW($D$2:$D$10)-1,1),4)
```

Copy formula down and right as needed.

If you do not want to see errors, you can include each formula in the `IFERROR` function - `IFERROR(...,"")`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! First Formula with the index gives me an error..

Comment: In the example it works, look carefully to see if all the parameters are specified correctly.